# How much performance does passing a canvas cost?

Tags: java, android, performance, canvas

Im developing a game based on a bunch of isometric tiles. I have the option to:

A:

```
for (i=0;i<numberoftiles;i++){

drawMap(canvas, i);

drawBuildings(canvas, i);

drawlivingbeings(canvas, i);

}
```

B:

```
for (i=0;i<numberoftiles;i++){

canvas.drawBitmap(maparray[i],.........)

 canvas.drawBitmap(buildingsarray[i],.........)

canvas.drawBitmap(peoplearray[i],.........)

}
```

Option A has the advantage of splitting the code into smaller segments, following good coding practice

Option B saves having to pass the Canvas Object for hundreds of times.

Which approach should I choose in terms of efficiency?

Comment: i've made some minor changes to your question, personally i just think the `what would you choose` just sounds too opinionated, but your question does seem to involve performance so that's what i changed it to

Comment: Neither. It's all pass-pointer-by-value, which means there's no copying or extra costs. At least none of significance - a function abstracting another function requires moving integer values one more time, but it's essentially insignificant. The JVM can probably optimize bits of your code to reduce that insignificant delay anyway

Comment: Do you have a real performance problem you're trying to solve? Seems like a premature/microoptimization that is highly unlikely to have any impact. Why not profile/benchmark both pieces of code and see for yourself? See [performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: The performance  of my game was struggling quite a bit depending on map/chunk size so i wanted to improve optimization. Chunking did it, but implementing that after writing the entire game without chunks was a bit of a pain lol. Thanks for the answers guys